Installing PyTorch 3D in WSL
All the below dependencies are installed and my Python version in conda is 3.9 and the torch version with CUDA is
torch installations
conda create -n pytorch3d python=3.9
conda activate pytorch3d
conda install pytorch=1.13.0 torchvision pytorch-cuda=11.6 -c pytorch -c nvidia
conda install -c fvcore -c iopath -c conda-forge fvcore iopath

While solving the environment in conda env - Initially found conflicts and conda was looking for incompatible packages.
Later, I got this prompt that 2.35 version was installed and found that nothing has been installed on the env.
Installed version 2.35
No PyTorch3D is installed here,
PyTorch3D not installed
